# Javascript string to lowercase to match db fields

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql

I have a form

```
<form action="_orders.php" method="get" autocomplete="off" name="cerca_db">
 <tr>
  <td class="main" width="170">Ricerca Cliente</td>
  <td><input type="hidden" name="action" value="check_sped_data" /></td>
  <td class="main"><p class="ciao" id="auto"><input id="searchField" name="searchField" type="text" onKeyPress="return disableEnterKey(event)"></p></td>
  <td width="25"></td>
  <td class="main"><input type="submit" value="Cerca"></td>
 </tr>
</form>
```

This is used to search in a mysql db table. Once the button is clicked it autocompletes all fields of another form based on the database record just found.

Now my problem is with autocomplete part because of case sensitive. I have already managed to extract data in lower case but i'm not able to transform input 
*searchField* to lower case before send to java function to match db record.

I actually found javascipt function to have autocomplete stuff. I only changed html and php part to match my needs, I didn't touch anything on java itself because i'm totaly a noob with it.

So now the form send the input to the javascript like this

```
$(function(){
  setAutoComplete("searchField", "results", "autocomplete.php?part=");
});
```

The automcomplete.php is need to extract data from db based on input and place in array to display under the input:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT a.customers_firstname, a.customers_lastname, a.customers_id, b.entry_company FROM customers a left join address_book b on a.customers_id = b.customers_id GROUP BY b.entry_cf");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
{
  $ricerca = array(strtolower($row['customers_firstname']) => strtolower($row['customers_lastname']));

  foreach ($ricerca as $key=>$data)
  {
    $edata[]=$data . ' ' . $key;
    $edata[].=$key .' ' . $data;
  } 

  $edata[].=(strtolower($row['entry_company']));
}
```

Now we have the array of names and company all lower case ready to match what is entered in the field. If the input is lowercase everything works fine, but if input is uppercase it doesn't match anything at all.

Do you guys have any solution on this or any idea how i can workout the case sensitive problem?

Edited: this is how data are pushed from db to the java script:

```
if(isset($_GET['part']) and $_GET['part'] != '')
{
         $results = array();

     $count = 0;
     foreach($extracted_data as $edata)
     {
         if( strpos($edata, $_GET['part']) === 0 )
            {
                 $results[] = $edata;
                 $count++;
                 if ($count == 10) break;
             }
     }
     echo json_encode($results);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Before submitting or sending information, call a javascript function which converts all characters to lowercase.
If your  element is named "YourInputID",
Example:

```
function convert()
{
    var a = document.getElementById("YourInputID").value;
    a = a.toString().toLowerCase();
    document.getElementById("YourInputID").value = a;
}
```

You could use javascript string function [reference here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tolowercase.asp) str.toLowerCase() to convert the string characters to lower.

Comment: i really don't know how to apply function in the form before submit it, can you please be more specific?

Comment: @Fabio, the issue here is that your form is being submitted using a function and you're not sure what that function does. So the best thing would either be to have a look at that function or to work out a way around the issue in the back end. Currently your PHP code forms an array but doesn't seem to return or search for anything; is there anything more in the file?

Answer (score 1):

This should get you on the right track:

```
document.getElementById('foo').addEventListener('keypress', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.value += String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode).toLowerCase(); 
});​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/m66c2/

Comment: i can't get it work, i tried to replace foo with input id wich is searchField but it makes autocomple not working, what am i missing?

Comment: The `e.preventDefault()` is likely preventing the event from reaching the autocomplete handler. Simply call the autocomplete event at the bottom of the keypress callback.

Comment: I'm sorry but i'm such a ignorant with java and stuff... Could you put a straight sample to make it works? I would really apreciated, thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

OK, firstly your PHP is going to have some problems. Where you say:

```
$edata[]=$data . ' ' . $key;
$edata[].=$key .' ' . $data;
```

That's going to access two different items in the array, which I assume you don't want to do. That's because the syntax `$array[]` is (sort of) short for using the `array_push()` method - each time it is accessed it adds to the array. The syntax `$array[].=$value` means the same as `$array[]=$value` as you can't effectively concatenate to an empty array item.

```
$edata_this='';
foreach ($ricerca as $key=>$data)
{
  $edata_this=$data . ' ' . $key;
  $edata_this.=$key .' ' . $data;
} 

$edata_this.=(strtolower($row['entry_company']));
$edata[]=$edata_this;
```

Now, if your issue is simply converting a JavaScript item to lower case, use the `String.toLowerCase()` method.

However I'm not entirely sure in the question which part you're actually needing to change or do a comparison on, so some more explanation might be useful.

Additionally you should always avoid using inline JavaScript such as onKeypress; as you're using jQuery try using its `$().keypress()` binding:

```
$('input[name="YOUR_NAME"]').keypress(function(){
  // your actions go here
});
```

Comment: $edata[]=$data . ' ' . $key;
        $edata[].=$key .' ' . $data;

i know i used this because name and surname can be insert in input in both ways so i had to add a double item in array to mach each way of wrinting first and last name. i still don't understand how i could use string.toLowerCase, i tried many way. thanks

Comment: Concatenating like that is fine, but you can't concat onto an empty array index. If you're simply adding two array items just use the `$edata[]=$value` syntax so that the code is clearer in its intent.

Comment: alright thanks but i still don't understand how to solve my issue, can you please help me out using String.toLowerCase() method ?

Comment: The issue is I'm not sure what you're doing. What format does the autocomplete.php file return the data in? What does the `setAutoComplete` function do with the returned data?

Comment: I managed to solve this issue. I strtolower the input isset. Thanks for your support

Comment: Glad you've solved it. Please could you add your answer with as much information as possible and accept it so that the question is completed?

Comment: I didn't add because solution was not really an answer to my question, i just made a workaround. Should i put anyway?